# on my second class called next class, last line of public array list search for price the .indexOf double cant be dereferenced?

Tags: java

I started looking up for result and getting the title of a book. When a user enter a keyword it will locate the book and display the author, price, and title of the book. My main issue is with my value price that i was trying to do indexOf, and lower the result down to one book. Any advice will be appreciated.

```
   public ArrayList<Test> searchForTitle( String searchString )
{
    ArrayList<Test> searchResult = new ArrayList<Test>();
    for ( Book currentBook : library )
    {
        if ( ( currentBook.getTitle() ).indexOf( searchString ) != -1 )
        searchResult.add( currentBook );
    }
    searchResult.trimToSize();
    return searchResult;
}

public ArrayList<Test> searchForAuthor( String searchString )
{
    ArrayList<Test> searchResult = new ArrayList<Test>();
    for ( Test currentBook : library )
    {
        if ( ( currentBook.getAuthor() ).indexOf( searchString ) != -1 )
        searchResult.add( currentBook );
    }
    searchResult.trimToSize();
    return searchResult;
}


   next class: 

    public static void main(String [] args ) {
    BookStore bs = new BookStore();

    String keyword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a keyword"  );
    System.out.println("Our book collection is:");
    System.out.println(bs.toString());

    ArrayList<Test> results = bs.searchForTitle(keyword);

    System.out.println("The search results for " + keyword + " are:");
    for( Test tempBook : results )
    System.out.println(tempBook.toString());
    String Author = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Author" );
    results = bs.searchForAuthor(Author);

    System.out.println("The search results for " + Author + " are:");
    for ( Book tempBook : results)
    System.out.println(tempBook.toString());

    double lowestprice = Math.min(price);
    String Lowest = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 

    "The lowest price           in the bookstore is: " + lowestprice);
    }
    }
   public ArrayList<Test> searchForPrice( String searchString )
    {
    ArrayList<Test> searchResult = new ArrayList<Test>();
    for ( Book currentBook : library )
    {
        if ( ( currentBook.getPrice() ).indexOf( searchString ) != -1 )
        searchResult.add( currentBook );
    }
    searchResult.trimToSize();
    return searchResult;
   }
   }


     public Test()
{
    title = "";
    author = "";
    price = 0.0;
}

public Test(String newTitle, String newAuthor, double newPrice )
{
    title = newTitle;
    author = newAuthor;
    price = newPrice;
}

public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

public String getAuthor()
{
    return author;
}

public double getPrice()
{
    return price;
}

public String toString()
{
    return ("title: " + title + "\t" + "author: " + author + "\t" +  "price: " + price );
}
     }
```

Comment: *"it show double value cannot be dereferenced?"* Don't make us guess: 1. What is the *exact* error message, and 2. What line does that error message refer to?

Comment: How exactly does an error in the code qualify as a `coding-style` question? *Please* don't tag-spam.

Comment: correct the title first, make your question specific, and please refer to the method (at least) that produces the error. we don't have time to read all your code

Comment: alright let me rephrase

Answer (score 0):

I think with this line:

```
 if ( ( currentBook.getPrice() ).indexOf( searchString ) != -1 )
```

you search within a `double`-Value a `String` cause the `searchString`is from Type `String`and `getPRice()`returns a double value. This is not a good solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `getPrice` method returns a `double`. But then you're doing this:

```
if ( ( currentBook.getPrice() ).indexOf( searchString ) != -1 )
```

...which tries to call `.indexOf` on the result of calling `getPrice`. `double` is a primitive type, it doesn't have methods, and if it did it wouldn't have `indexOf`.

If you really want to apply a search term to the `double` value, you'll have to convert it to a string:

```
if ( String.valueOf( currentBook.getPrice() ).indexOf( searchString ) != -1 )
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But it seems odd to check a search string against a price.

Comment: The main idea i need to do is returning the book with lowest price to user, a method going through the library for books of an author, then return a list of such books. A second method returning books price less than a given number. Where should I start focusing sir.